# Need help fixing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement [this word wrap algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-18-word-wrap/) in Java. My program takes in the number of paragraphs to wrap, the maximum line length, and the input text. For example:

```
1
5
This is a test.
```

However, after it takes in the input text and runs the algorithm, I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at DynamicProgramming.main(DynamicProgramming.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Could it be possible that I have a typo from translating the above code from C++ to Java, or is there kind of error in this logic that would be causing this exception? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DynamicProgramming {
    static int P;
    static int M;
    static String[] inputLine;

    public static void printNeatly(int M, int[] inputLineLengths) {
        int n = inputLineLengths.length;
        double[][] extraSpaces = new double[n][n];
        double[][] lineCost = new double[n][n];
        double[] optimalTotalCost = new double[n];
        int[] optimizedLengths = new int[n];

        for (int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
            extraSpaces[i][i] = M - inputLineLengths[i-1];

            for (int j=i+1; j <= n; j++) {
                extraSpaces[i][j] = extraSpaces[i][j-1] - inputLineLengths[j-1] -1;
            }
        }

        for (int i=1; i<= n; i++) {
            for (int j=i; j <=n; j++) {
                if (extraSpaces[i][j] < 0) {
                    lineCost[i][j] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                }
                else if (j == n && extraSpaces[i][j] >= 0) {
                    lineCost[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    lineCost[i][j] = extraSpaces[i][j]*extraSpaces[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        optimalTotalCost[0] = 0;
        for (int j=1; j <= n; j++) {
            optimalTotalCost[j] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int i=0; i <= j; i++) {
                if (optimalTotalCost[i-1] != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY && lineCost[i][j] != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY &&
                        (optimalTotalCost[i-1] + lineCost[i][j] < optimalTotalCost[j])) {
                    optimalTotalCost[j] = optimalTotalCost[i-1] + lineCost[i][j];
                    optimizedLengths[j] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int printOutput(int[] optimizedLengths, int n) {
        int k;

        if (optimizedLengths[n] == 1) {
            k = 1;
        }
        else {
            k = printOutput(optimizedLengths, optimizedLengths[n]-1);
        }

        System.out.println(optimizedLengths[n]);
        return k;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        P = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int[] inputLineLengths = new int[]{};


        for (int i=1; i <= P; i++) {
            M = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            inputLine = scanner.nextLine().split("[ ]+");
            inputLineLengths[i] = inputLine.length;
            printNeatly(M, inputLineLengths);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I've never used a Java debugger before, actually. Would jdb be alright for this?

Comment: Your IDE should come with a nice GUI debugger. For code like this, also consider writing unit tests. They can be an immense help to find bugs.

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with the command-line debugger. I always used Eclipse's... Sorry I can't help with that

Comment: Thanks. I use IntelliJ IDEA, so I'll look into it.

Comment: Which line is line 74?

Comment: @DSlomer64: `inputLineLengths[i] = inputLine.length;` in `main()`

Comment: My guess is that i >= inputLineLengths.length

Comment: Your array has length 0 because of this line: `int[] inputLineLengths = new int[]{};`

Comment: Leave off the `{}` for starters. Scratch that idea.

Comment: You don't have to use a debugger.  The exception message tells you which line the problem is on, and you can insert System.out.println statements to print out stuff just ahead of the problem statement.  Print out, eg, the index value and the size of the array you're indexing.  Then work backwards from there to figure out how those variables got their values, inserting println statements as needed to see other intermediate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the `printNeatly` method:

You get the length of the array like this:

```
int n = inputLineLengths.length;
```

But in your loops, you go up to and including `n`:

```
for (int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
```

You need to stop just before, because arrays (in Java) are indexed from `0` to `n-1` (so it's also very likely that you mean to start your arrays from `0`, and not `1`)

```
for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks. I have some index values like `[i-1]` that obviously won't work when `i=0`, so it looks like I'll have to do some restructuring.

Comment: Having values with `[i-1]` isn't that big of a deal, especially since you started purposefully at `i=1`; but as soon as `i=n` and you try to read that index of the array, you'll get errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `inputLineLengths` array is initialized to a length of `0`, so you can't put anything into the array.

Initialize it to a length of `P` first.

```
int[] inputLineLengths = new int[P];
```

Second, your `for` loop needs to range over valid index values, which are from `0` to `array's length - 1`.  Change your `for` loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < P; i++) {
```

You have other `for` loops outside of `main` that need to be changed similarly.